# PrimeFaces: dealing with incomplete components.js

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2, apache-tomee, tomee-7

I'm getting some complaints that the p:toolbar of my applications is not working. Looking personally on one of the workstations that the problem happened, Firefox 49 console had the following error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list[Learn More]components.js.jsf:21:18950
```

Opening components.js I could see that the file was incomplete, it stopped loading on this line:

```
PrimeFaces.widget.Menu=PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend ...
```

PrimeFaces version is 6.0.5.

I'd like to understand two things:

1. Why it happens
2. If it happens, how to fix it inside the
   application

1) My applications are not open to general public, so the first page the user will see is login. When I update the PrimeFaces version, the download of the new version of components.js will be triggered on the login page right? My best guess is that the user has saved his credentials on the browser and his connection was slow, so the page didn't even completed loading when he submitted the login form, aborting the components.js download, but since the file exists locally the browser tries to use it.

Considering that there is a pattern on the problem (file stops loading approximately on the middle), could it be some server issue? I'm using Apache TomEE 7.0.1(Tomcat 8.5.3). Server log has the following exceptions several times:

```
16-Oct-2016 22:08:08.469 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-11] org.apache.myfaces.application.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest Error trying to load resource components.js with library primefaces :java.io.IOException: Pipe quebrado
 org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Pipe quebrado
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:380)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:420)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.close(OutputBuffer.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.close(CoyoteOutputStream.java:150)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:620)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at br.com.spdata.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe quebrado
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1241)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:355)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:324)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:580)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:213)
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:375)
    ... 43 more


17-Oct-2016 08:34:32.650 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.myfaces.application.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest Error trying to load resource components.js with library primefaces :Stream closed
 java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.ensureOpen(InflaterInputStream.java:67)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:142)
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResource$JarInputStreamWrapper.read(AbstractArchiveResource.java:249)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ResourceHandlerImpl.pipeBytes(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:655)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ResourceHandlerImpl.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:605)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler.handleResourceRequest(PrimeResourceHandler.java:87)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.handleResourceRequest(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:59)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:190)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.openejb.server.httpd.EEFilter.doFilter(EEFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at br.com.spdata.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBSecurityListener$RequestCapturer.invoke(OpenEJBSecurityListener.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

2) Considering that at least jQuery loaded, I came with the following script, but it doesn't replaces the corrupted cached file.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function()                     
        {                  
            try
            {
                var ctx = "#{request.contextPath}";

                if(typeof PrimeFaces == 'undefined')
                {
                    $.getScript(ctx + '/javax.faces.resource/core.js.jsf?ln=primefaces')
                }

                if(typeof PrimeFaces.widget.TriStateCheckbox == 'undefined') // last component on the file
                {
                    $.getScript(ctx + '/javax.faces.resource/components.js.jsf?ln=primefaces')
                }       
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            }       
        });             
        //]]>   
    </script>       
</h:body>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, since I was receiving the same error trace and it only happened to me in Firefox.
The error says that some fonts or styles of Primefaces were not loaded, but verifying the application it seems that everything was loaded well although this error was shown.
After much research I have found the problem [here](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=55047&start=10).

The log messages correspond to HTTP requests that are canceled immediately after submitting them, before the server could send the response.
the "Cache Race With Red" feature was activated in Firefox 59 (released March 13) and seems to be the cause.

With this feature, Firefox send requests for cached resources concurrently to the local disk cache and the actual network server.
Whichever result arrives first is used, the other request is canceled (which would cause a log message about a "Broken pipe", as with other connection aborts).

This feature can be disabled in Firefox in `about:config` by setting `network.http.rcwn.enabled` to `false`. So I stopped getting log messages after setting this to false.
In my case the log messages seem to be benign and this I could be ignored.

[image: Config Race Feature Firefox]

I hope this can help others who encountered the same problem.